# how to remove all special characters from a string, java script

Tags: javascript

I have a multiline string like

```
"Abc: XXXX
 BCD: YYYYY
{'abc': 'bcd'}"
```

Now when I copy this to a buffer, then basically some special characters get added, like "\n\t" etc, So how I can remove all those special characters in Java Script?

Regards,
-M-

Answer (score 0):

\n is a representation for new line, \t is for tabs - if you still wish it to be multiline you need to leave them alone.

Comment: Basically I am getting this kind of data from curl response, now I want to decode it based on the Header types, so I do not have any other choice other than decoding this type of data. But I have to decode it after storing it to some buffer, for that I need to remove all the special characters such that I can apply awk on that.

Comment: Split the strings on '\n' to get the lines then split on '\t' to get the fields for tab separated data.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using Regex:

```
var txt = "hello\t world.\n have a\t great day";
alert(txt);
txt = txt.replace(/(\n|\t|\r)/g, '');
alert(txt);
```